# C - Freeing Malloc. Getting error while running

Tags: c, malloc

I dont know what is wrong with my program. I allocated memory using malloc using a loop and when i go to free it, it gives me the following error:

```
"*** glibc detected *** ./assignment4: free(): invalid pointer: 0x08eeb196 ***
```

This error is accompanied by a list which has the title memory map. The loop runs from 1 to 7. The weird thing is when i free the `[0]` value of the string i don't get any error. The error only comes up with i try to free `[1]` to `[7]` which was malloced using a loop.

```
void lineParse()
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("specification.txt", "r");

    char ** listofdetails; 
    listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char*)*6);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        listofdetails[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);
        fgets(listofdetails[i], 40, fp);
        /*printf("%s \n", listofdetails[i]);*/
        /*free(listofdetails[i]);*/
    }


    char ** stringOne; 
    stringOne = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringOne[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringOne[0] = strtok(listofdetails[0], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringOne[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringOne[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringTwo; 
    stringTwo = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringTwo[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringTwo[0] = strtok(listofdetails[1], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringTwo[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringTwo[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringThree; 
    stringThree = malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringThree[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringThree[0] = strtok(listofdetails[2], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringThree[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringThree[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringFour; 
    stringFour= malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringFour[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringFour[0] = strtok(listofdetails[3], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringFour[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringFour[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringFive; 
    stringFive= malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringFive[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringFive[0] = strtok(listofdetails[4], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringFive[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringFive[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    char ** stringSix; 
    stringSix= malloc(sizeof(char*)*8);

    stringSix[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringSix[0] = strtok(listofdetails[5], " ");

    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        stringSix[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
        stringSix[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf(" %s \n", stringSixrows);*/

    { //This works fine
        free(stringOne[0]);
        free(stringTwo[0]);
        free(stringThree[0]);
        free(stringFour[0]);
        free(stringFive[0]);
        free(stringSix[0]);
    }



    for(i=1;i<8;i++) //But here is where the problem arises. If i remove this code is runs fine.
    {
        free(stringOne[i]);
        free(stringTwo[i]);
        free(stringThree[i]);
        free(stringFour[i]);
        free(stringFive[i]);
        free(stringSix[i]);
    }


    free(listofdetails);
    free(stringOne);
    free(stringTwo);
    free(stringThree);
    free(stringFour);
    free(stringFive);
    free(stringSix);
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Calling `fgets(listofdetails[i], 40, fp)` with a 40-character string looks a little bit risky when taking into consideration the new-line character (`\n`) that might be added at the end of the string, as well as the additional 0-character required to make it a null-terminated string. You might need to call `fgets` with 39 or even 38. I advise you to check this function on the manual.

Comment: @barakmanos: `fgets` is one of the very few functions in the standard library, where passing the full size is OK. At most one less than that many characters are read and the result is always 0-terminated.

Comment: @mafso: OK, good to know, that's why I wrote everything with a tiny bit of skepticism... Thanks for the info :)

Comment: You know, `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at how you use `strtok()`:

```
for(i=1; i<8; i++) {
    stringOne[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
    stringOne[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

....    

for(i=1; i<8; i++) {
    free(stringOne[i]);
}
```

Issues:

1. You very clearly leak the memory that you allocate with `malloc()`.
2. `strtok()` itself allocates no memory.
3. Later in the program you attempt to free the pointer returned by `strtok()` which will cause undefined behavior.

It's pretty clear that you don't understand how `strtok()` works. So let's try to describe it.

Let's take a string: `"hello world and people"`.

```
char[] s = "hello world and people";
char * token = strtok(s, " ");

// The memory as s is now: "hello\0world and people\0"
// token points to "hello\0world and people"

token = strtok(NULL, " ");

// The memory at s is now: hello\0world\0and people\0"
// token points to "world\0and people"

token = strtok(NULL, " ");

// The memory at s is now: hello\0world\0and\0people\0"
// token points to "and\0people"

token = strtok(NULL, " ");

// The memory at s is now: hello\0world\0and\0people\0"
// token points to "people"

token = strtok(NULL, " ");

// The memory at s is still: hello\0world\0and\0people\0"
// token points to NULL
```

Note that at no point did we allocate any additional memory (other than the space for the original string which in this case was allocated on the stack). `strtok()` mutates that original string, replacing the delimiter with null characters.